# Typescript TypeORM find return type mismatch with defiend entity type

Tags: node.js, typescript, entity, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have the following code snippet in `infrastructure` module:

```
import { Student } from "core"
import { Repository } from "./Repository"
import { Database } from "../../db"
export class UserRepository<Student> extends Repository<Student> {
    private _repository = Database.AppDataSource.getRepository(Student);
    public override async GetById (id: number): Promise<Student | null> {
        return await this._repository.findOneBy({ id: id });
    }
    public override async ListAll (): Promise<Student[]> {
        return await this._repository.find();
    }
}
```

The type `Student` is defined in `core` module.
Build error:

```
Data/Repositories/StudentRepository.ts:7:9 - error TS2322: Type 'import("/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/build/index").Student | null' is not assignable to type 'Student | null'.
  Type 'import("/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/build/index").Student' is not assignable to type 'Student'.
    'Student' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'import("/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/build/index").Student'.

7         return await this._repository.findOneBy({ id: id });
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Data/Repositories/StudentRepository.ts:10:9 - error TS2322: Type 'import("/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/build/index").Student[]' is not assignable to type 'Student[]'.
  Type 'import("/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/build/index").Student' is not assignable to type 'Student'.
    'Student' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'import("/usr/src/Node.JSRestAPI/src/core/build/index").Student'.

10         return await this._repository.find();
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you importing Student from the core library, instead of some entity file, where you defined your class?